# Preserving order of values in associative array

Tags: php, sorting, associative-array

Lets say I have an array like

```
$array = array(
    'abc' => true,
    'def' => true,
    'ghi' => true,
    'jkl' => false
);
```

This is an over simplified example, in actuality the values are objects which have a status of 'active' or 'inactive'.

```
class myObject {
    var $tab_name;
    var $active;
}
```

This is used to build an array of tabs for a tab view where order is important.

Now if I toggle one of my values

```
$array['abc'] = false;
$array['jkl'] = true;
```

How can I reorder the array (actually an ordered map) so that the `true` values remain at the front, retaining their order (any additions should be appended) and the `false` values remain at the rear (order NOT important)?

IE. I expect the output to be:

```
array (
    'def' => true,
    'ghi' => true,
    'jkl' => true,
    'abc' => false
);
```

All I know beforehand is the key of the value being toggled.

Comment: Using [usort](http://prototype.php.net/function.usort) with a customised callback to work with your map

Comment: @MarkBaker From the Docs "If two members compare as equal, their relative order in the sorted array is undefined." I need to preserve the order of active elements.

Comment: So you need to pass the actual array to your callback function/closure as well.... if you're using a closure, then this is easily done using `use`... if you can provide a basic example of your array of objects, then I can look at posting a code solution

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm worried taking that approach, php will still decide to reorder, since the callback is only responsible for return an int rather than performing the swap.

Comment: But the value that the usort callback returns is entirely in the developer's control, and can be as precise as you choose to make it

Comment: @MarkBaker I understand what you're saying. Passing the whole array still requires finding the next key and comparing. Emphasis on the finding part. I'm now looking into `array_keys` and looping to find an insert position.

Comment: Passing the whole array to a closure via `use` allows you to test the keys for each of the two results as well; so if `true` for both values, your callback return should be based on comparing the keys

Comment: @MarkBaker Are the order of arguments passed to the closure guaranteed to be the same as they are in the array? There is nothing related to that in the docs. What happens if they change between PHP versions? I'm still left with finding which comes first in the original array.

Comment: No they aren't, but as long as you values are unique, then you can use those to identify the keys from the full array passed in the `use` and ensure that the trues are ordered by their key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear that any of the builtin array sorting functions let you access both key and value at the same time, which seems to be what you need here, since the sorting algorithms behind the scenes don't look to be stable.

I scratched this up (coded for clarity rather than elegance), it might help. It doesn't do "in place" sorting, but if the dataset isn't too huge, it might do what you need to.

```
function group_array($ary){
    $t = array();
    $f = array();
    $res = array();
    foreach (array_keys($ary) as $k){ //Assuming that you're 100% sure that the input array keys are already ordered
        if ($ary[$k] == 'true') {
            $t[] = $k;
        } else if ($ary[$k] == 'false') {
            $f[] = $k;
        }
    }
    foreach ($t as $true_key){
        $res[$true_key] = 'true';
    }
    foreach ($f as $false_key){
        $res[$false_key] = 'false';
    }

    return $res;
}
```

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for. But rather than rebuilding the arrays, an in-place swap should suffice. The key is mapping names to indice via `array_keys`. Thanks :)

Comment: Happy to help! Enjoy your holidays. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the array uses "Active" and "Inactive" as you specified, you can just use asort($array), which will return all "Active" values at the top since it's an alpha sort.